# Unable to push code to Azure DevOps because of wrong cached credentials

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-repos

It seems I have got somewhere wrong credentials and are cached which is not allowing me to push the code to Azure DevOps (Azure Repository).

I am using Git Bash as a client tool.

**Error Message as below:**

```
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://xxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/dms/_git/reponame/'
```

I tried the below solutions but have had no luck

1. Stop and start Git bash
2. `git config --global credential.helper "cache --timeout=60"`

3 Renamed `C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache to C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\GitCredentialManager\tenant.cache.bak`
Even deleted tenant.cache still no fun...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Good News is that Git Bash (as well as Git GUI) are typically configured to use Windows Credentials Mgr.

Try this:

- Start > Credentials ("Credential Manager") > Generic credentials
- *DELETE* your Azure DevOps URL (it might be called "azure", it might be called "MicrosofAccount")
- Try pushing to Azure DevOps again.  You should be prompted for username/password.

In parallel, you could also try:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
git config --global --add credential.helper manager
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, mate, works like a charm!